# How to hide files with certain extensions in the fish shell?

Tags: bash, shell, fish

I don't want to see .pyc files when I do the ls command from within the fish shell. With bash I could do an alias. With fish I tried putting the following into ~/.config/fish/config.fish

```
function ls
  command ls --hide="*.pyc"
end
```

But it doesn't work. I get

```
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]
```

Comment: Looks like the parameter `--hide` is not being accepted. Have you tried ls with hide option in interactive shell ?? And are you using Linux or BSD ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're apparently using the BSD ls command. On Mac OS X I get the same error because /bin/ls doesn't recognize any long options. On OS X do `brew install coreutils` to get the GNU ls which does support `--hide`.

Also, you probably want the body of your function to be

```
command ls --hide="*.pyc" $argv
```

You can also have your function behave differently depending on such things as whether or not the output is going to a tty. Here's my function:

```
function ls --description 'List contents of directory'
    set -l param --color=auto
    if isatty 1
        set param $param --indicator-style=classify
    end
    command ls $param $argv
end
```